# Using a 2.10-only SBT plugin in a project that's cross-built against 2.9

Tags: scala, sbt

Suppose I've got a SBT 0.13 project that's cross-built against Scala 2.9.3 and 2.10.4. I want to use an SBT plugin ([sbt-coveralls](https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-coveralls)) for the 2.10 build only, because the plugin isn't available for 2.9.

I know that I could use `CrossVersion` to conditionally add the plugin settings to the 2.10 build, but that doesn't help with the fact that `addSbtPlugin` isn't going to find anything for the 2.9 build, etc.

I'm assuming this is impossible (short of some really messy ad-hoc shell scripting) but I'm not an SBT wizard, and it would be nice to be surprised by the mysteries of SBT in a good way for once.

Comment: Just a side note - I think this problem is even more complicated. I think you cannot use `CrossVersion` to conditionally add settings.

Comment: @lpiepiora: I'm following [this demo project](https://github.com/scala/scala-module-dependency-sample), and that part seems to work just fine.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/scala/scala-module-dependency-sample) the `CrossVersion` is used in a setting macro, and a `scalaVersion.value` can be used. You want to use it outside of the macro. I've followed [github discussion](https://github.com/twitter/scalding/issues/931) and I don't think, the solution suggested there will work.

Answer (score 4):

Found this horrible hack of a workaround, but it does seem to work:

```scala
resolvers <++= scalaVersion {
  case v if v startsWith( "2.12" ) =>
    Seq.empty

  case _ =>
    addSbtPlugin( "org.scoverage" % "sbt-scoverage" % "1.0.4" )
    addSbtPlugin( "org.scoverage" % "sbt-coveralls" % "1.0.0" )
    Seq( Classpaths.sbtPluginReleases )
}
```

Comment: the problem with this is that if you have any scoverage setting on your build.sbt, then the build will fail.

Comment: I successfully used this hack on an scoverage-enabled project, but maybe I missed something?

Comment: Did you have any scoverage keys on your build.sbt?

Comment: Long overdue, but no, I didn't. Your comment is spot-on.

Answer (score 3):

I might misunderstand the question, but I think you may be confused with sbt's vs a project's versions of Scala.

You cannot use a plugin that's incompatible with sbt - the runtime. If a plugin doesn't support the version of Scala sbt uses under the covers the plugin is deemed incompatible and hence sbt will refuse starting up. sbt 0.13.5 uses 2.10.4 so the plugins can only use Scala API 2.10.4. That's why `addSbtPlugin` offers no `%%`.

For projects, it's different. Here you could use whatever version you want regardless of the version sbt uses and hence the plugins. Once you've `addSbtPlugin`'ed a plugin, the plugin's available in a project, and to enable it, add the settings to projects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think I'm even more confused now—in [this branch of Scalding](https://github.com/twitter/scalding/tree/scoverage), if you switch the `scalaVersion` from 2.10.4 to 2.9.3, you get an `unresolved dependency: org.scoverage#scalac-scoverage-plugin_2.9.3...`. It also does use `%%` in `addSbtPlugin` (although switching to `%` doesn't seem to make a difference).

Comment: The error you're seeing is because sbt-scoverage is modifying the libraryDependencies setting -- that's pretty unusual for a plugin to do, but I guess it makes sense in this case. As for why scoveralls uses the `%%`, my guess without looking closely at the code is that they supply versions that are slightly different based on the Scala version used by sbt itself.

Comment: To be more clear, what you're seeing is fairly unusual -- this plugin (plugins, really) is doing a bit more invasive updates to the project settings than you would typically see a plugin doing. Perhaps this is reasonable given the instrumentation that's needed.