# Conditional addSbtPlugin based on scalaVersion

Tags: sbt

I'm using a plugin (sbt-scapegoat) which only works for Scala 2.11.

Can I have a conditional addSbtPlugin based on scalaVersion? Like:

```
if (scalaVersion.value.startsWith("2.11")) addSbtPlugin("com.sksamuel.scapegoat" %% "sbt-scapegoat" % "0.94.6")
```

How can I do this in SBT?

Jianshi

Comment: Can you describe what your use case is a little more please? In particular is it a multi-module build? Cross-built? What Scala versions? I only ask because it's a little tricky to answer, as the best answer depends on your situation.

Comment: Hi Dale, It's a single-module build. I'm not using cross-build feature. Scala version is 2.11.6 or 2.10.5

Comment: How is it Scala version 2.11.6 or version 2.10.5? Not sure what you mean

Comment: It has no sense. Current sbt 0.13.x use scala 2.10.4. You can not change scala version for sbt. You can choose scala version for dependencies - not for plugins

Comment: In my case, I need to disable scoverage for Scala 2.12 builds since it doesn't support that version yet. In other words, the project definition will depend on the active Scala version, not on the sbt Scala version.

Comment: Found a workaround, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558700/using-a-2-10-only-sbt-plugin-in-a-project-thats-cross-built-against-2-9/31582587#31582587

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**tl;dr** It's not possible given the description of the problem.

There are *at least* two build configurations involved in a sbt project - the real project (you want to bet your money on) and the meta build for the build of your project. Yes, I know it sounds a little weird, but it's a very powerful concept IMHO.

See [sbt is recursive](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Organizing-Build.html#sbt+is+recursive):

> The project directory is another build inside your build, which knows how to build your build. To distinguish the builds, we sometimes use the term proper build to refer to your build, and meta-build to refer to the build in project. The projects inside the metabuild can do anything any other project can do. Your build definition is an sbt project.

sbt runs atop Scala and requires a strict version of it. No way to change it unless you fancy spending time on things you should really not be touching in the first place :)

What you can do is to apply the plugin in `project/plugins.sbt` and then, in the project, apply **the settings** of the plugin selectively, per `scalaVersion` of the project's build *not* the meta-build's itself.

It's not that complicated as the answer reads, but explaining simple concepts is usually not an easy task for me. Have fun with sbt! It's gonna pay you back very soon when used properly.

Answer (score 3):

Updated answer for 2020: You can use `.filter` on `addSbtPlugin`.

For example, the following works:

```scala
val scalafixEnabled = System.getProperty("SCALAFIX", "").trim.nonEmpty

addSbtPlugin("ch.epfl.scala" % "sbt-scalafix" % "0.9.14").filter(_ => scalafixEnabled)
```

Comment: your answer ignores dependence on Scala version