# sbt : scalaVersion value inside plugins.sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

Is there a way to get the value of **scalaVersion** setting inside **plugins.sbt** ?

I tried to do the following inside `plugins.sbt`:

```
logLevel := Level.Warn

resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.8.7")

val version = scalaVersion.value
```

And this is the error I get  :

> error :  value can only be used within a task or setting macro, such as :=,
> +=, ++=, Def.task, or Def.setting.

What I want to achieve inside **plugins.sbt** is to retrieve the value of scalaVersion setting and use that val with addSbtPlugin like the following :

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.8.7").filter(_ => version == "2.12")
```

Comment: Could you post whole code snippet? This error says that you have value declaration in wrong place.

Comment: @Ivan Kurchenko , I updated the question and posted the whole plugins.sbt file , but I guess it has to do only with that specific line in which am declaring that val. As you see am declaring it directly , not inside an sbt task neither a setting

Comment: And you can try to elaborate what you are trying to achieve with that version in `plugins.sbt`. This might be informative for you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11768730/2359227

Comment: @Tomer Shetah , the goal is to use that scala version with addSbtPlugin

Comment: @Tomer Shetah, I have updated my question , I described what I want to achieve

Comment: Why would you want to do that? play 2.8.7 is  Scala 2.12, what is the problem you are trying to resolve?

Comment: @Tomer Shetah, I want to conditionally load sbt plugins depending on the scalaVersion (you're right but  play 2.8 and scala 2.12 is just an example here , it could be any other plugin or scalaVersion)

Comment: @Tomer Shetah , have a look at Golly's answer here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815817/conditional-addsbtplugin-based-on-scalaversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error says that you can't read settings value outside of task or setting execution scope, so instead of just declaring field, you should use inside another task or settings, e.g. :

```
lazy val customVersion = settingKey[String]("Custom version for sake of example")

customVersion := {
  //`.value` referenced inside `customVersion` settings declaration, so sbt can evaluate customVersion in scope of other settings/task evaluations.
  "Custom version" + scalaVersion.value
}
```

Comment: And how can I retrieve the value of the new customVersion setting inside plugins.sbt. I think I would fall in the first case since I can't use value outside tasks / settings scope . My goal is to retrieve the scalaVersion and then use it with addSbtPlugin inside plugins.sbt .

Comment: @Helix112 aren't sbt add plugin only for certain Scala version?