# How to conditionally load sbt plugins?

Tags: scala, sbt

In a project cross compiled to multiple scala versions, it is possible to have a plugin (sbt-coverage) only loaded for a certain scala version (2.11) and skip loading the plugin and ignoring its keys on the other scala versions?

Comment: Looks like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558700/using-a-2-10-only-sbt-plugin-in-a-project-thats-cross-built-against-2-9 "Using a 2.10 only sbt plugin in a project that's cross-built against 2.9") might have useful info.

Comment: Certain project scala versions or sbt scala versions?

Comment: @nafg project scala version. Sbt scala version being fixed.